# How to add annotations to this dygraph?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Anyone familiar with the javascript dygraph library? I want to add an annotation to this dygraph, but it looks quite different from what's in the tutorial online.

```
g = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("visualization"),
chart_data, {
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
    labelsSeparateLines: false,
    labelsKMB: true,
    labels: ["X", "Val"],
    legend: 'onmouseover',
    colors: ["rgb(88,143,235)"],
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    //title: '<?  ?>',
    //xlabel: '<?= $xAxisLabel ?>',
    //ylabel: '<?= $yAxisLabel ?>',
    axisLineColor: 'white',
    //valueRange: <?= $yAxisRangeStr ?>,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    dateWindow: [(d.getTime() - 2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), d.getTime()],
    underlayCallback: function (ctx, area, dygraph) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.strokeRect(area.x, area.y, area.w, area.h);
    }
    // echo($chart["dygraphs-scaling"]) ?>
    // drawXGrid: false
});
```

Comment: Please, when you get a moment, consider visiting the [Markdown editing page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for guidance on formatting.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking or what you have tried. Dygraphs documentation for annotations is here: http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html . Suggest modifying your question with more info, and then potentially creating a jsfiddle to show what you have tried. You can start with:  http://jsfiddle.net/dygraphs/NtBPk/

Comment: In particular, it's hard to know how to help without knowing what chart_data looks like. Providing a demo link via dygraphs.com/fiddle will help us help you.